# How do I ensure that a python package module saves results to a sub-directory of that package?

Tags: python, path, package

I'm creating a package with the following structure

```
/package
    __init__.py
    /sub_package_1
        __init__.py
        other_stuff.py
    /sub_package_2
        __init__.py
        calc_stuff.py
        /results_dir
```

I want to ensure that `calc_stuff.py` will save results to `/results_dir`, unless otherwise specified (yes, I'm not entirely certain having a results directory in my package is the best idea, but it should work well for now). However, since I don't know from where, or on which machine `calc_stuff` will be run, I need the package, or at least `my_calc.py`, to know where it is saved.

So far the two approaches I have tried:

```
from os import path
saved_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'results_dir')
```

and

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
filepath = resource_filename(__name__, 'results_dir')
```

have only given me paths relative to the root of the package.

What do I need to do to ensure a statement along the lines of:

```
pickle.dump(my_data,open(os.path.join(full_path, 
                                      'results_dir', 
                                      'results.pkl'), 'wb')
```

Will result in a pickle file being saved into `results_dir` ?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Code and data should be separate; users should be able to run the code on multiple arbitrary data sets in multiple arbitrary directories without copying the code.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not entirely certain having a results directory in my package is the best idea*, me either :)

But, if you were to put a function like the following inside a module in subpackage2, it should return a path consisting of (module path minus filename, 'results_dir', the filename you passed the function as an argument):

```
def get_save_path(filename):
    import os
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "results_dir", filename)
```

```
C:\Users\me\workspaces\workspace-oxygen\test36\TestPackage\results_dir\foo.ext
```

Comment: This still only goes as far back as the root of the package - i.e. if the full path is /home/Projects/package/...., all this gives me is package/... , which I can't save to.

Comment: What Python version are you using, for 3.6 I'm getting the whole path.

Comment: Well, feeling a little embarrassed, but 2.7. It really seems to be time to change..., although I found this:     os.path.realpath(`__file__`),    which seems to work.

Comment: @user1245262 don't feel embarrassed, there are still many packages / codebases that haven't updated, requiring use of 2.7.  Anyway, you should self-answer and accept it if that ended up working :)